# Why It’s impossible to run android app on other platform directly? (and the result of IcedRobot project)

Tags: android, apk

I have 2 questions:

1. My first question is how can I **directly** run an android application under anything else than Android? Actually I found some responses that introduce emulators or Chrome. I know them & actually tried some of them. But I want to know is there any **scientific paper** to explain the main reason that **why It’s impossible to run android app on other platform directly?**
2. It’s good to say that I found **“IcedRobot project”** that was created to do this, but I guessed that it has stopped since 2012. My second question is **why this good project has been stopped?**

I mean running android apps on Linux or windows directly...

Comment: You can take most of the logic of android apps and port it to most platforms seeing as it is Java. Most of the android only calls can be roughly compared to a GUI platform.

Comment: err, because the apps are specifically made to use the android sdk?

Comment: @MeetTitan I mean running android apps on linux or windows directly...

Comment: I understand what you mean. Android apps are written with instructions that computers do not know how to interpret. Try looking into an emulator if you do not have the java source available to port to another GUI frontend.

Comment: @MeetTitan you point my question, what is this android instruction that doesn't allow computers to interpret & run them?  I want a scientific paper (or some thing like this) for this.

Comment: The libraries used for most of android are as far as I know deeply embedded into android, and without running the android environment on your PC vis a vis an emulator, you would likely need to supply and modify the android framework.